# Reading Data from a Scanner Connected Through Serial Port

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, serial-port

I have an AspNetCore app that i am developing, I have to connect a barcode/Qr code scanner to the client computer, and I have to get the data on the server side and use the data for validation and pass the result to the client side.

Right now, I connected the scanner through **Serial Port** and can read the data from the barcode/Qr codes, but I think this is because the client/server is being run on the same computer now since I'm developing it.

I would like to ask that after I deploy the app, is there is a way to get the data on the server side after the Qr code/barcode have been scanned on the client side?

Below is my current code which i use to access the data through the serial port.

I created an instance of the serial port and leave it open so that qr codes/barcodes can be scanned continuously

```
static SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
public ActionResult SelectedPN(String nameobj)
{
    pn_No= nameobj;
          
    _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

    _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mySerialPort_Data);

    if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        try
        {
            _serialPort.Open();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
}
```

When data is received, the Action method which will process the data is called `_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mySerialPort_Data);`

And below is the function

```
public void mySerialPort_Data(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_serialPort.ReadExisting() != null)
    {
        newpageList = _db.Categories1;
        string data = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
        barcode = data.Split(";");
        codeValue = barcode[0].Substring(barcode[0].IndexOf(":") + 1);
        GetCurrent();
        //SelectedPN(pn_No);
    }
    //_serialPort.Close();
}
```

This solution works now in development, but I am concerned about when I publish the app. The client and server won't be on the same computer, so this approach probably won't work.

Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by formatting those code snippets correctly :D

Comment: How do you mean please?

Comment: I am on the cell phone right now and I see whitespace for the most part.

Comment: There, I fixed it. On topic: As you already guessed, as soon as the server does not run on the same machine the Scanner is attached to, it cannot get its readings. That means: a) Your _client_ needs to take the scans, b) your server needs an endpoint to receive scans from clients and return results and c) your clients must use those.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it! Can you please give a detailed explanation as an answer